# What is the type of <><TagA/><TagB/></> in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have some code like

```
const icons = <>
    <Play onClick={() => playEpisode(episode)}/>
    <MoreHorizontal onClick={() => openEpisode(episode)}/>
</>;
```

but I don't know what the type of `icons` is.

Comment: If you temporarily make it `let` not `const` and put `icons = 42;` on the next line a compiler would tell you what type it is in the error message.

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/everything-you-need-to-know-about-react-eaedf53238c4/

Answer (score 1):

`icons` type is `JSX.Element` and `<></>`is called Fragment. It can also be written as `<React.Fragment></React.Fragment>`.
You can read an official docs for this: [React.Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

Hope this can help!

Answer (score 0):

It is a `React.Fragment`. See https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html.

Answer (score 0):

Basically everything in React is object. You can check it out by `console.log(typeof <>"Anything"</>)`